# Drag one picturebox to picturebox, it drags them all

Tags: c#

When i drag one picturebox, it drags both of mine. Because in the pbxMap_DragDrop method i have to call both of the methods that should fire when i drag one.

```
 private void pbxMap_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            myDetectMouse.setMinotaur(e, myMap.myCells);
            myDetectMouse.setTheseus(e, myMap.myCells);
        }
```

SetTheseus:

```
public void setTheseus(DragEventArgs e, List<Cell> cells)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
            {
                int[] mapData = myMapController.getMapData(i, cells);
                int column = mapData[0];
                int row = mapData[1];
                int right = mapData[2];
                int bottom = mapData[3];

                Point RelativeMouseLoc = myMapController.myMap.myForm.pbxMap.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

                if (RelativeMouseLoc.X > column &&
                    RelativeMouseLoc.X < column + myMapController.myMap.myCellSize
                    && RelativeMouseLoc.Y > row && RelativeMouseLoc.Y <
                    row + myMapController.myMap.myCellSize)
                {
                    myMapController.myMap.myCells[i].hasTheseus = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    myMapController.myMap.myCells[i].hasTheseus = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

SetMinotaur is much the same but replace hasTheseus with hasMinotaur. As soon as a cell "hasTheseus" or "hasMinotaur" it will be drawn to the cell.

So it draws them both when i drag one because they both get set in pbxMap_DragDrop.

I thought i could have multiple event handlers for pbxMap_DragDrop depending on which picturebox was dragged.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `sender` parameter to determine whether you want to move the minotaur or Theseus. It would look something like this:

```
var pic = (PictureBox)sender;
if (pic.Name == "minotaur")
{
    myDetectMouse.setMinotaur(e, myMap.myCells);
}
else
{
    myDetectMouse.setTheseus(e, myMap.myCells);
}
```

If you don't want to use the `Name` property, you can use something else like the `Tag` property - just make sure you set it for each of the `PictureBox` objects.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this doesn't seem to work. The pic.Name doesn't appear to be "minotaur" if the name property is minotaur. EG, the else works no matter which picturebox i drag.

Comment: You could debug it and see what's the actual value. Maybe it's just a typo.

Comment: Oh right, the pictureBox that is the sender is actually the pictureBox that i am dragging to, (destination pictureBox) not the dragged picturebox. This complicates things.

Comment: In that case you'll need to have an event for when the drag starts and set which object should be moved in an instance variable, then check that variable in your current DragDrop event handler.